# Trying to divide sum/ count of date by each step in SQL - Grouping Expression Sequence is Empty

Tags: sql, group-by, apache-spark-sql, count, union

I am having an issue with this SQL code. I am trying to divide sum/ by the count of a date. I keep getting the grouping expressions sequence is empty, and 'TableBlank.rep_date' is not an aggregate function error. I have tried with `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` statements and I'm still getting the error.

```
SELECT 
    rep_date,
    1 AS AssignRank,
    StepCompSum,
    'StepCompA' AS FunCat,
    CAST( StepCompSum / COUNT( rep_date ) AS double ) AS ParticRate

FROM
    TableBlank

WHERE
    FunCat = 'StepCompA'

UNION

SELECT 
    rep_date,
    2 AS AssignRank,
    StepCompSum,
    'StepCompB' AS FunCat,
    CAST( StepCompSum / COUNT( rep_date ) AS double ) AS ParticRate

FROM
    TableBlank

WHERE
    FunCat = 'StepCompB'

UNION

SELECT 
    rep_date,
    3 AS AssignRank,
    StepCompSum,
    'StepCompC' AS FunCat,
    CAST( StepCompSum / COUNT( rep_date ) AS double ) AS ParticRate

FROM
    TableBlank

WHERE
    FunCat = 'StepCompC'

GROUP BY
    rep_date,
    StepCompSum
```

Comment: Please post a SQLFiddle or DBFiddle with sample data, otherwise we cannot really help you.

Comment: Why are you using `UNION` with a repeated query? Is there a reason you can't do `SELECT ... FROM TableBlank WHERE FunCat IN ( 'StepCompA', 'StepCompB' , 'StepCompC' )` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, emphasis on minimal.  Do you get the error if you run only the first query?

Comment: DDL and sample data would also help.

Comment: and paste the actual error message

Comment: You need a GROUP BY when aggregating data with SUM, MIN, MAX, and AVG, just as the error message tells you. You need to find a good basic SQL tutorial or book.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to know without sample data, but this might work:

```
SELECT 
  rep_date
, 2 AS AssignRank
, StepCompSum
, FunCat
, CAST(StepCompSum / (COUNT(rep_date) OVER (PARTITION BY FunCat)) AS double) AS ParticRate

FROM TableBlank
```

Although, I suspect what you are wanting from the `CAST` is to get the result to not be an integer.  Here's what you'll get:

2 / 3 = 1  (because, integer math)
cast(1 as double) = 1.000
when you probably expect 0.667

You need to either cast the values first, or just include a value of the appropriate type in the expression:

```
StepCompSum * 1.0 / (COUNT(rep_date) OVER (PARTITION BY FunCat))
```